# Is there a way to save partial results of a loop in case of power cut in R?

Tags: r

I was running a very heavy loop for about 2 days, and on a power outage I lost all the data, since it was stored to RAM. Where I live power comes and goes and isn't very reliable. I would like to know if there is any way to store the result of every single iteration of a loop in non-volatile storage, just in case the power goes away once again while the loop is still running

Comment: In your loop you could write part of output in the form of csv or text file after every `n` iterations so that you don't loose complete data if power goes out.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to append to a `.csv` file for every iteration of your loop. In my case `Demo.csv` is a ";" delimited file. Make sure you set the working directory correctly and also keep in mind that the dimensions have to match so in my case I append to a 2 column data structure.

**Code**

```
for(i in seq(1, 10)){
  
  # Whatever your loop does
  
  tmp1 <- i^i - 10 
  tmp2 <- 11
  
  # append to Demo.csv for every iteration
  
  write.table(cbind(tmp1, tmp2), file = "Demo.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ";",
              col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  
  
}
```